# UWP canvas dynamic content

Tags: c#, canvas, uwp, binding

I want to be able to dynamically add different (self-created) "widgets" to my canvas and position them using `Canvas.Top` and `Canvas.Left`.

I have been able to add items using `Canvas.Children.Add()`, but I can't figure out how to create a binding to the `Top` and `Left` values.
Would it be a better idea to somehow bind the contents of the `Canvas` to a list and create all the bindings in XAML? Then again, how would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't know the bindings in UWP, you can see this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-quickstart).

Depending on your situation, you can consider using MVVM for binding, creating a `ViewModel` in Code-Behind and using `Binding` in the xaml to bind related properties.

**CanvasPageViewModel.cs**

```cs
public class CanvasPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double _rectTop;
    public double RectTop
    {
        get => _rectTop;
        set
        {
            _rectTop = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private double _rectLeft;
    public double RectLeft
    {
        get => _rectLeft;
        set
        {
            _rectLeft = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**CanvasPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
public CanvasPageViewModel viewModel = new CanvasPageViewModel();
public CanvasPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = viewModel;
    viewModel.RectTop = 20;
    viewModel.RectLeft = 100;
}
```

**CanvasPage.xaml**

```xml
<Grid>
    <Canvas Width="500" Height="500" Background="White">
        <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Blue"
                   Canvas.Top="{Binding RectTop}"
                   Canvas.Left="{Binding RectLeft}"/>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

This is a simple example. If you want to modify the position of the control later, you can directly modify the data source and the UI will synchronize.

---

**Update**

If you need to manually add child elements of Canvas, you can use this method:

```cs
var myRect = new Rectangle() 
{ 
    Height = 50, 
    Width = 100, 
    Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue)
};

myCanvas.Children.Add(myRect);
```

But if you want to bind the created Rectangle element, as you said, bind the `Canvas.Left` property, you can write:

```cs
public CanvasPageViewModel viewModel = new CanvasPageViewModel();
public CanvasPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    var myRect = new Rectangle() 
    { 
        Height = 50, 
        Width = 100, 
        Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue) 
    };

    Binding leftBinding = new Binding() 
    { 
        Path = new PropertyPath("RectLeft"),
        Mode=BindingMode.OneWay 
    };
    myRect.SetBinding(Canvas.LeftProperty, leftBinding);
    myCanvas.Children.Add(myRect);
}
```

Best regards.

Comment: Thank you, but it seems like I didn't phrase my question correctly. What I am looking for is a way to add _new_ UI elements to a Canvas, preferably using some sort of binding.

Comment: Hi,do you want to use Canvas like `ListView.ItemsSource`? This is probably not in line with the design of the binding. Bind meaning binding data instead of binding the `UIElement`. You can manually add child elements using `myCanvas.Children.Add(uiElement)`, but it is not recommended to use bindings to complete it.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was looking for. But using `Canvas.Children.Add()`, I couldn't figure out how to create bindings for `Canvas.Top` and `Canvas.Left`, since they are `DependencyProperty`s originating from the `Canvas`.